# How to uninstall MySql.Data Version 6.8.0-alpha from Visual Studio (NuGet)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I am using the Entity Framework with a MySQL database.

When trying to make a query on the database, I get the following error:

```
Model2.ssdl(2,96) : error 0004: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I would like to roll back to the previous version, that seemed to work.

When trying to uninstall MySql.Data in the NuGet package manager console, i get the following error:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.8.0-alpha
Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'MySql.Data 6.8.0-alpha' because 'MySQL.Data.Entities 6.7.4.1' depends on it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Uninstall-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.8.0-alpha
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UninstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-Force` parameter for `Uninstall-Package` command.

```
Uninstall-Package MySql.Data -Force
```

Then you can install the latest stable version back:

```
Install-Package Mysql.Data
```

Comment: Thanks atleast it removed it. Now I am getting another error, which you can see here: http://pastebin.com/22AYrHkq
Notice the line that says: LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 6.7.4.0 redirected to 6.8.0.0.

Comment: @Kenci Check your web.config. You should also change the assembly version somewhere.